# Is there any public dataset on Bangla Language handwriting available?

Tags: nlp

I am willing to work on a natural language processing project that encompasses learning from Bangla handwritten texts. Hence, I am looking for publicly available Bangla handwritten texts' dataset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The author ([Ujjwal Bhattacharya](https://www.isical.ac.in/~ujjwal/)) of this paper:

**[An End-to-End System for Bangla Online Handwriting Recognition](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7814092/)**

has an application for the dataset on their [download page](https://www.isical.ac.in/~ujjwal/download/database.html) (direct [PDF](https://www.isical.ac.in/~ujjwal/download/appform.pdf)  link). You'll also find some sample datasets ([for example](https://www.isical.ac.in/~ujjwal/download/Banglabasiccharacter.html)).

(Interestingly, also an [Android App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=bangla.handWritingRecognizer))